# PHP Session - Include header.html once when using htaccess and Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, .htaccess, session

My page have 2 sections, header and content. To not reload header in the navigation, I'm using Ajax to get the html content from the page that referes to the clicked link. At the same time, I'm using htaccess to redirect everything to a index.php file, so I can control every request and validade the same, return a html content. The problem is: when I access the page for the first time, I put the header in the template. Then, I click in a link, so Ajax is call and make a redirect to index.php, because the htaccess rule. But, in that call, the content is returned and the header too. So I have a index page inside a index page, and the header is duplicated. Trying to know when the header is already loaded to not load it again, I try to use sessions, but I don't know how to know when the header was really loaded or not. I don't want to use any information from the client-side, like headers, for security reasons.

index.php

```
<?php
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION["header_already_loaded"])){
    $_SESSION["header_already_loaded"] = true;
    require_once "header.html";
}

$routes = array(
    "/" => "home.html",
    "/profile" => "profile.html",
    "/config" => "config.html"
);

$uri = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];

$file = isset($routes[$uri]) ? $routes[$uri] : $routes["/"];
echo '<div id="content">';
require_once $file;
echo '</div>';

?>
```

header.html

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $(document).on('click', "a", function(e){

        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            url: this.pathname,
            type: 'post',
            success: function(ret) {

                $("#content").html(ret);

            }
        });

        return false;
    });

</script>

<style>
    #content{
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
</style>

<div id="header">
    <a href="/">Home</a>
    <a href="/profile">Profile</a>
    <a href="/config">Configurations</a>
</div>
```

htaccess:

```
DirectorySlash Off

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
```

Comment: Sessions is a wrong tool for the job. Make the first load work the same way: it only loads the header and the corresponding JS, which then loads the body from a _different_ url.

Comment: Sorry, I don't undestand. Can you give me a example?

Comment: Redesign your application so that index.php only loaded a header, and the body was served by other script.

Comment: Ok, I will try something like that. Thanks!